why when using random in access 2016 I am getting the 7th record always as a start?
enter image description hereI am trying to get a random record from access table but when I first start the app it is always picking record number 7. After that the random is working fine picking different random record.
Here is my code, I don't see where in my code that specify for record number 7 to be the first record selected when I start the app?
Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim rs As Recordset

    Randomize
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,Rnd(StarterID) As RandomValue FROM starter where asked = False ORDER BY Rnd(StarterID))")
    
    GlobalVars.starterid = rs!starterid
    ques = rs!starterquestion
    Answer1 = rs!Ans1
    Answer2 = rs!Ans2
    Answer3 = rs!Ans3
    Answer4 = rs!Ans4
    GlobalVars.correctAnswer = rs!correctAnswer
    
    Me.question.Value = ques
    Me.Ans1.Caption = Answer1
    Me.Ans2.Caption = Answer2
    Me.Ans3.Caption = Answer3
    Me.Ans4.Caption = Answer4
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing
    
End Sub

here is the table:
the table

Sounds like your call to Randomize is being ignored, since that's exactly how Access would behave when not initializing the random number generator. I'm not entirely sure if the database engine and the VBE runtime share a random number generator.
A trick that's often used is multiplying the ID with Timer() and making it negative. That's not truly random but based on the system time and the ID, but most of the time that's good enough.
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,Rnd(-1 * StarterID * Timer()) As RandomValue FROM starter where asked = False ORDER BY Rnd(-1 * StarterID * Timer()))")

